# Firebase is not working on iOS for production builds

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, cloud-storage

I did a mobile application using Firebase (Analytics, Crashlytics and Storage). It is working fine on Android and also on iOS so I released the application. Now I notice that none of the Firebase services the app is using is working on iOS when the app is installed from the App Store If I install the app on a device directly from XCode, all is working fine.

Does anyone has an idea of what it may be and how to fix it? I am new to iOS.

Thank you!

All is running fine on Android. The problem appears only on iOS when the app is installed from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, if it happens to you, generate the archive again and verify it on TestFlight, then publish it on the store if it works. I think something went wrong with my first archive.